# EF Core Foreign Key: incompatible types

Tags: c#, orm, entity-framework-core, foreign-keys, ef-core-3.1

I looked through many similar questions, but I find no applicable solution.

I get the following error message during tests:

> System.InvalidOperationException : The relationship from 'Product.FeatureType' to 'FeatureType.Product' with foreign key properties {'Type' : string} cannot target the primary key {'Id' : Guid} because it is not compatible. Configure a principal key or a set of compatible foreign key properties for this relationship.

The foreign key should be `FeatureType`'s `Type` field.

This only happens, when I set the type of `Product.Type` as a `string` and as not as a `Guid`. But it should be a `string`, rather than a `Guid`. I do not understand at all what is the problem here. I do the project in a DB-first approach and the database can be created without a problem with SQL using this logic. I appreciate every help.

Edit: Here is my MSSQL model:

```sql
CREATE TABLE [Core].[FeatureType](
    [id] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [int_id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [type] [varchar](50) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    [description] [uniqueidentifier] NULL,
    [SysStartTime] [datetime2](7) GENERATED ALWAYS AS ROW START NOT NULL,
    [SysEndTime] [datetime2](7) GENERATED ALWAYS AS ROW END NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_FeatureType] PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED
(
    [id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY],
    PERIOD FOR SYSTEM_TIME ([SysStartTime], [SysEndTime])
) ON [PRIMARY]
WITH
(
SYSTEM_VERSIONING = ON ( HISTORY_TABLE = [Core].[FeatureTypeHistory] )
)
GO

CREATE TABLE [Core].[Product](
        [id] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL, 
        [name] [varchar](100) NOT NULL UNIQUE, 
        [type] [varchar](50) NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES [Core].[FeatureType](type),
        [SysStartTime] [datetime2](7) GENERATED ALWAYS AS ROW START NOT NULL,
        [SysEndTime] [datetime2](7) GENERATED ALWAYS AS ROW END NOT NULL,
        CONSTRAINT [PK_Product] PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED ([id] ASC)
        WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) 
        ON [PRIMARY],
        PERIOD FOR SYSTEM_TIME ([SysStartTime], [SysEndTime])
    ) ON [PRIMARY] WITH (SYSTEM_VERSIONING = ON ( HISTORY_TABLE = [Core].[ProductHistory] ))
GO
```

In my understanding, this should work because the `FeatureType` table's `Type` column is `UNIQUE`.

[image: Tables]

I have the following models:

```
public class Product : IDBModel
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }

    public DateTime SysStartTime { get; set; }
    public DateTime SysEndTime { get; set; }

    public FeatureType FeatureType { get; }
}

public class FeatureType : IDBModel
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public Guid? Description { get; set; }

    public DateTime SysStartTime { get; set; }
    public DateTime SysEndTime { get; set; }

    public TxtID TxtIDDescription { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Feature> Feature { get; }

    public ICollection<Product> Product { get; }
 }
```

And the following related context configuration:

```
public virtual DbSet<Product> Product { get; set; }
public virtual DbSet<FeatureType> FeatureType { get; set; }
...

modelBuilder.Entity<Product>(entity =>
        {
            entity.ToTable("Product", CoreSchema)
                .HasKey(k => new { k.Id }) 
                .HasName("PK_Product");
            entity.Property(a => a.Id).HasColumnName("id");
            entity.Property(a => a.Name).HasColumnName("name").IsRequired();
            entity.Property(a => a.Type).HasColumnName("type").HasMaxLength(50).IsRequired().IsUnicode(false);
            entity.Property(e => e.SysStartTime).HasColumnName("SysStartTime").ValueGeneratedOnAddOrUpdate();
            entity.Property(e => e.SysEndTime).HasColumnName("SysEndTime").ValueGeneratedOnAddOrUpdate();
            entity.HasOne(p => p.FeatureType)
                .WithMany(d => d.Product)
                .HasForeignKey(p => p.Type)
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);
        });

modelBuilder.Entity<FeatureAttributeSet>(entity =>
        {
            entity.ToTable("FeatureAttributeSet", "Core")
                .HasKey(e => new { e.Id })
                .HasName("PK_FeatureAttributeSet");

            entity.Property(e => e.Id).HasColumnName("id").IsRequired();
            entity.Property(e => e.AttributeSetId).HasColumnName("as_id").IsRequired();
            entity.Property(e => e.FeatureId).HasColumnName("feature_id").IsRequired();

            entity.Property(e => e.SysStartTime).ValueGeneratedOnAddOrUpdate();
            entity.Property(e => e.SysEndTime).ValueGeneratedOnAddOrUpdate();

            entity.HasOne(d => d.AttributeSet)
                        .WithMany(p => p.FeatureAttributeSet)
                        .HasForeignKey(d => d.AttributeSetId)
                        .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade)
                        .HasConstraintName("FK_FeatureAttributeSet_AttributeSet");
            entity.HasOne(d => d.Feature)
                        .WithMany(p => p.FeatureAttributeSet)
                        .HasForeignKey(d => d.FeatureId)
                        .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict)
                        .HasConstraintName("FK_FeatureAttributeSet_Feature");
        });
```

Comment: *But it should be a string* -- Why? Because it's a string in the database? If so, there can't be a foreign key in the database.

Comment: @GertArnold The FeatureType.Type is a unique string. However I see what you are saying, but I can create the DB and query against it. As the string is unique, in my understanding it can be used as a foreign key, can't it?

Comment: In a join statement the db will apply implicit conversion from string to guid (or the reverse, I don;t know), but it won't allow a foreign key. You should probably find this situation when checking the database schema.

Comment: Actually, it would help to show this part of the database model.

Comment: It seems that all you need is a value conversion, but I can only tell if I see the db model.

Comment: @GertArnold sorry for the late edit, I added the SQL used to create the DB. Could you please take a look if you have the time? Thanks. :D

Comment: I posted an answer. One thing isn't clear to me. Your database model has a 1:n relationship, but it shows as 1:1. I assumed that the DDL statements tell the truth.

Comment: @GertArnold I am not quite sure why it shows as 1:1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can model this in EF by using a [value conversion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/value-conversions).

The first step is to change the type of `Product.Type`:

```cs
public class Product
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime SysStartTime { get; set; }
    public DateTime SysEndTime { get; set; }

    public Guid Type { get; set; } // <= Guid, not string
    public FeatureType FeatureType { get; }
}
```

This satisfies EF's requirement that primary key and foreign key properties should have the same type.

But that alone would generate SQL that throws an exception because the database type is different. That's where value conversion are helpful. Just add one line in `OnModelCreating`:

```cs
entity.ToTable("Product")
    .HasKey(k => new { k.Id })
    .HasName("PK_Product");
// To convert string value from the database:
entity.Property(e => e.Type).HasConversion<string>();
...
```

Now EF accepts the association and also knows how to generate correct SQL for queries and inserts.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to configure the PrincipalKey. The PrincipalKey will allow us to define the reference key with a unique restriction which will be the destination of the relationship.
So you can use like this

```
 modelBuilder.Entity<Product>(entity =>
    {
            entity.ToTable("Product", CoreSchema)
                .HasKey(k => new { k.Id }) 
                .HasName("PK_Product");
            entity.Property(a => a.Id).HasColumnName("id");
            entity.Property(a => a.Name).HasColumnName("name").IsRequired();
            entity.Property(a => a.Type).HasColumnName("type").HasMaxLength(50).IsRequired().IsUnicode(false);
            entity.Property(e => e.SysStartTime).HasColumnName("SysStartTime").ValueGeneratedOnAddOrUpdate();
            entity.Property(e => e.SysEndTime).HasColumnName("SysEndTime").ValueGeneratedOnAddOrUpdate();
            entity.HasOne(p => p.FeatureType)
                .WithMany(d => d.Product)
                .HasPrincipalKey(p => p.Type)
                .HasForeignKey(p => p.Type)
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);
        });
```

Comment: Did you actually test this?

Comment: Yeah, you can see this
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.metadata.builders.referencereferencebuilder.hasprincipalkey?view=efcore-6.0

Comment: *Typically you would only call this method if you want to use a property(s) other than the primary key as the principal property(s)* -- That's not the case here and it doesn't fix the PK/FK type mismatch.

Answer (score 0):

The foreign key that you specify in your model builder statement for the FeatureType of Product in `.HasForeignKey(p => p.Type)` must be the same type as the primary key of FeatureType. Because the Id property of FeatureType is a Guid, Type on Product must also be of type Guid to be used as the foreign key for the relationship with FeatureType.

Is there a reason that you can't change the type of the *Type* property to Guid?

Comment: Yes, unfortunately. FeatureType.Type is a unique string in the database.

Comment: The easiest answer in that case may be to add another column that is a GUID that can hold the reference. Your database engine likely cannot enforce the GUID to string constraint that you are trying to make right now. Your key types really should match. Even if it doesn't cause an issue now, it likely will in the future.